Showing empty collection ListBox
If I want to display contents of the Dictionary in the ListBox, I have used a BindingSource. It works well, and it works well for my custom collection, too. However, if the collection (e.g. Dictionary) is empty, the ListBox still shows one line. In case of a dictionary, the line reads "(Collection)". In case of a custom collection, the line has class name (i.e. Object.ToString).
With following code ListBox1 shows two lines, as it should:
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}
ListBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(dic, Nothing)

With following code Listbox1 shows one line "(Collection)" instead of being empty:
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
ListBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(dic, Nothing)

With empty list there is no problem:
ListBox1.DataSource = New List(Of String)()
Example of empty and non-empty ListBoxs

If I assign an empty List to a ListBox, the box is empty. Why is the box not empty when populate it with empty Dictionary?

ListBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(dic.ToList(), Nothing).

@dr.null it will display nicely but if the data is changing, the new List won't reflect that and the ui won't be updated. Anyway the New BindingSource doesn't allow for that anyway so maybe it's fine.

@dr.null is right, though, a Dictionary is not a good object to use as a datasource. Use a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> or List<(string, string)>, or better yet, List<customClass>

Thank you @dr.null. Actually, I can simply use ListBox1.DataSource = dic.ToList(). BindingSource is not anyway updating the ListBox if I add something to the Dictionary.

@RoperttoIV Yes, the data source must implement the IList (List, BindingList, BindingSource...) or IListSource (DataSet, DataTable...).

@djv Calling dic.ToList() means the data source is List(Of KeyValuePair(Of string, string)).  To change an item here, you need to replace it with a new KeyValuePair and call BindingSource.ResetBindings(false) method. Yes, too much.

@RoperttoIV the reason is that ToList() creates a new object which is a copy of the dictionary into a list. Updating the dictionary is not updating the new list, to which you have no reference other than in the BindingSource. That could be edited with a lot of messy casting. But it's not worth it. Keep a reference to a list of something else.

@RoperttoIV Sorry, didn't notice you were asking. Create a model (class) and add two public properties (Key, Value) and bind a BindingList(Of ThatModel) instance to the ListBox1.DataSource. Try.
